# ImageMagick draw rectangle with special corners

Tags: imagemagick, mask, rounded-corners

Hi I would like to create a mask image with "special corners" I am calling them special because I don't really know how to call them in english here is what I would like to achieve:

[image]


what I am using now is

```
convert xc:black -size 300x300 -fill white -draw "roundrectangle 3,3,296,296,5,5"
```

but this gives me rounded corners. 
Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: "photo corners"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it.

```
convert -size 300x300 xc:none                   \
   -shave 10 -bordercolor black -border 10      \
   -fill black -draw "polyline 0,0 30,0 0,30"   \
   \( +clone -flip \) -gravity north -composite \
   \( +clone -flop \) -gravity south -composite -background white -flatten result.png
```

That says... *"Draw a rectangle your full size and transparent, shave 10 pixels off all round and add a 10 pixel black border (easier than doing the maths and making a 280x280 and adding 10 on each side). Draw a triangle in the top-left. Copy the whole shape and flip it and draw it on top of the original. Copy the whole shape and flop it and draw it again on the original. Now make all the transparent areas white."*

[image]

Here is another way - maybe a little easier. Draw the original square, then copy it, enlarge it by square-root(2) (i.e. 141%), thicken the borders, rotate 45 degrees and composite it onto itself. Kinda depends how your brain works!

```
magick -size 300x300 xc:none -shave 10 -bordercolor black -border 10 \
  \( +clone -scale 142% -shave 30 -border 30 -rotate 45 \)  \
  -gravity center -composite -background white -flatten result.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a page showing how to do what you want along with other effects https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#rounded

This is the code from the page:

```
convert thumbnail.gif -alpha set  -compose DstOut \
      \( -size 20x15 xc:none -draw "polygon 0,0  0,14 19,0" \
         -write mpr:triangle  +delete \) \
      \( mpr:triangle             \) -gravity northwest -composite \
      \( mpr:triangle -flip       \) -gravity southwest -composite \
      \( mpr:triangle -flop       \) -gravity northeast -composite \
      \( mpr:triangle -rotate 180 \) -gravity southeast -composite \
      corner_cutoff.png
```

You should check out the examples as there is another method you could use for smaller images.